# In C++11, is it wise (or even safe) to use std::unique_lock<std::mutex> as a class member? If so, are there any guidelines?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Is it wise (or even safe) to use std::unique_lock as a class member?  If so, are there any guidelines?

My thinking in using std::unique_lock was to ensure that the mutex is unlocked in the case of an exception being thrown.

The following code gives an example of how I'm currently using the unique_lock.  I would like to know if I'm going in the wrong direction or not before the project grows too much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>


class WorkerClass {
private:
    std::thread workerThread;
    bool workerThreadRunning;
    int workerThreadInterval;

    int sharedResource;

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> workerMutex;

public:
    WorkerClass() {
        workerThreadRunning = false;
        workerThreadInterval = 2;

        sharedResource = 0;

        workerMutex = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);

        unlockMutex();
    }


    ~WorkerClass() {
        stopWork();
    }


    void startWork() {
        workerThreadRunning = true;
        workerThread = std::thread(&WorkerClass::workerThreadMethod,
                                   this);
    }


    void stopWork() {
        lockMutex();
        if (workerThreadRunning) {
            workerThreadRunning = false;
            unlockMutex();
            workerThread.join();
        }else {
            unlockMutex();
        }
    }


    void lockMutex() {
        try {
            workerMutex.lock();
        }catch (std::system_error &error) {
            std::cout << "Already locked" << std::endl;
        }
    }


    void unlockMutex() {
        try {
            workerMutex.unlock();
        }catch (std::system_error &error) {
            std::cout << "Already unlocked" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    int getSharedResource() {
        int result;
        lockMutex();
        result = sharedResource;
        unlockMutex();
        return result;
    }


    void workerThreadMethod() {
        bool isRunning = true;

        while (isRunning) {
            lockMutex();
            sharedResource++;
            std::cout << "WorkerThread:  sharedResource = "
                      << sharedResource << std::endl;
            isRunning = workerThreadRunning;
            unlockMutex();

            sleep(workerThreadInterval);
        }
    }
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sharedResource;
    WorkerClass *worker = new WorkerClass();

    std::cout << "ThisThread: Starting work..." << std::endl;
    worker->startWork();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sleep(1);

        sharedResource = worker->getSharedResource();
        std::cout << "ThisThread: sharedResource = "
                  << sharedResource << std::endl;
    }

    worker->stopWork();

    std::cout << "Done..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. The only case where the `unique_lock` is destroyed is when you destroy the class, which means that the mutex is going to be immediately destroyed thereafter. `unique_lock` and `lock_guard` are generally used locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is actually quite bad. storing a `std::unique_lock` or `std::lock_guard` as a member variable misses the point of scoped locking, and locking in general.

the idea is to have shared lock between threads, but each one temporary locks the shared resource the lock protects. the wrapper object makes it return-from-function safe and exception-safe.

you first should think about your shared resource. in the context of "Worker" I'd imagine some task queue. then, that task queue is associated with a some lock. each worker locks that lock with scoped-wrapper for queuing a task or dequeuing it. there is no real reason to keep the lock locked as long as some instance of a worker thread is alive, it should lock it when it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to do that for a number of reasons. The first you're already "handling" with the try-catch block: two threads attempting to lock the same lock results in an exception. If you want non-blocking lock attempts you should use [`try_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/lock) instead.

The second reason is that when [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) is stack-allocated in the scope of the duration of the lock, then when it is destructed it will unlock the resource for you. This means it is exception safe, if `workerThread.join()` throws in your current code then the lock will remain acquired.